# How to set the default value while adding a new column

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I am using the following vba code to execute an sql statement in Access 2007:

```
SQL = "ALTER TABLE " & strNEW & _
      " ADD COLUMN ([GolfLengte] INT) DEFAULT " & _
      strTableName

DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL)
```

Wich prints:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_GL_850 ADD COLUMN ([GolfLengte] INT) DEFAULT 850
```

The query should update an already existing table with already existing records:

```
    Table1
+--------------+----------+----------+
| Column1      |  Column2 |  Column3 |                  
+--------------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     | 
+--------------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     | 
+--------------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+
```

What I would like is another column added with `In every record` the value that is written in the variable `strTableName` like so:

```
    Table1              strTableName = 850
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Column1      |  Column2 |  Column3 |GolfLengte|         
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     |   850    |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     |   850    |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     |   850    |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
|       x      |    x     |    x     |   850    |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Seems to me that it is a valid SQL statement, but for some reason vba keeps telling me that there is a syntax error while highlighting

```
DoCmd.RunSQL (SQL)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `ALTER TABLE` change table schema, but not data.

You must `"UPDATE " & strNEW & " SET GolfLengte = " & strTableName` after `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_GL_850
ADD GolfLengte INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(850)
```

apologies....this is SQL, I missed the VBA Access part of the question (it's early)

try:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_GL_850 ADD COLUMN GolfLengte INT DEFAULT 850
```

Comment: This gave me an error : `Error 3320 while executing`  `missing ),] or element in expression`

Comment: This doesnt work either, no error, but my "golfLengte" column stays empty